# Converting jquery code to Angular controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Hi I have following function in jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $(".side-nav .collapse").on("hide.bs.collapse", function () {
        $(this).prev().find(".fa").eq(1).removeClass("fa-angle-right").addClass("fa-angle-down");
    });
    $('.side-nav .collapse').on("show.bs.collapse", function () {
        $(this).prev().find(".fa").eq(1).removeClass("fa-angle-down").addClass("fa-angle-right");
    });
})
```

I want to use this in Angular controller. Please let me know how to do it.
Thans

Comment: You should use that (converted) in a directive not in a controller. Please try something.

Comment: Just wrap it into very simple (< 20 lines) directive.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is wrap everything in a directive you can get started with directives here http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/
if you insist in doing it on controller then you can use

```
angular.element('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```